# why accessing property of database query output giving error in one system not in other system

Tags: sql, node.js, database

max is select query result. And I am getting it as NULL.
var maxLevel = max[0].level;    //This line is giving error in one system,
as "Cannot read property 'level' of undefined"
while no error in other system.

I want to get no error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 


Your requirement  is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

before getting `max[0].level` why don't you try `console.log` that `max[0]`. i am sure that way you can get the answer to your question, and check there is property which call **level** .And also it's better to add more information about your question.